# Run the same Selenium test suite multiple times

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using webdriver to automate some actions on webpage and have created a selenium test suite test.xml

```
<suite name="testSuite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    ...all the tests in this suite...
</suite>
```

for the purpose of testing, I want to run this suite multiple times or run it constantly for 1-2 hours (a single run takes only 2-3 minutes).

Is there a simple way to make the suite run again and again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and standard way for

> to run this suite multiple times or run it constantly for 1-2 hours

it's called [CI](http://continuous%20integration) servers. Most popular are:

- [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)
- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)
- [Teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Since you've put *Java* tag - the first two will do the job just fine. They all  include reporting on the number of tests that pass and fail, and can help link test failures to source code changes in order to more quickly identify issues.

By running tests on a regular, repeatable basis, you can start tracking other metrics as well – for example, is your test coverage improving over time? One team at Red Gate actually fails builds if new code causes the test coverage to drop compared to the previous build – a great example of using monitoring to encourage the development behaviour your team is aiming for!